# How can I ask TeraCopy 3 to retry all failed copies?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, teracopy

When I use  TeraCopy 3 to copy files, sometimes some file copies fail:

[image]

How can I ask TeraCopy 3 to retry all failed copies at once?

---

On TeraCopy 2 I can retry all failed copies with:

1. Click on Skipped:

   [image]
2. Select all failed copies and click on `Copy`:

   [image]
3. Done:

   [image]

but no idea how to do that in TeraCopy 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once done, at the top, you see buttons for Skipped, errors and ok. These make selections if you press them.

After you press Next, you can then perform the next action on that selection, such as test, copy, etc... This is the new way designed to make it easier.

But if you want to mimic the old TeraCopy 2 behavior, you can do the following:

Right-click the list, Select, Successful to select only those that were successful.

Then right-click the list, Remove Selected. Your new list will only contain the items that were not successful.

---

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Nice demo. Can you tell me what you use to generate that gif?

Comment: [LICEcap](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/24774/903). Not a huge fan though, e.g. [limited in features](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/78441/903).

Comment: Thanks :) Will toy around with it. :)